# Python re find start and end index of group match

Tags: python, python-re

Python's re match objects have .start() and .end() methods on the match object.
I want to find the start and end index of a group match. How can I do this?
Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> REGEX = re.compile(r'h(?P<num>[0-9]{3})p')
>>> test = "hello h889p something"
>>> match = REGEX.search(test)
>>> match.group('num')
'889'
>>> match.start()
6
>>> match.end()
11
>>> match.group('num').start()                  # just trying this. Didn't work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'start'
>>> REGEX.groupindex
mappingproxy({'num': 1})                        # this is the index of the group in the regex, not the index of the group match, so not what I'm looking for.
```

The expected output above is (7, 10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide [`Match.start`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.start) (and `Match.end`) with a group name to get the start (end) position of a group:

```py
>>> import re
>>> REGEX = re.compile(r'h(?P<num>[0-9]{3})p')
>>> test = "hello h889p something"
>>> match = REGEX.search(test)
>>> match.start('num')
7
>>> match.end('num')
10
```

An advantage of this approach over using `str.index` as suggested in other answers is that you do not run into problems if the group string occurs multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

A slight modification on [the existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67047257/13386979) is to use `index` to find the whole group, rather than the starting and ending characters of the group:

```
import re
REGEX = re.compile(r'h(?P<num>[0-9]{3})p')
test = "hello h889p something"
match = REGEX.search(test)
group = match.group('num')

# modification here to find the start point
idx = test.index(group)

# find the end point using len of group
output = (idx, idx + len(group)) #(7, 10)
```

This checks for the whole string `"889"` when determining the index.  So there is a little less potential for error then checking for the first `8` and the first `9`, though it is still not perfect (i.e. if `"889"` appears earlier in the string, not surrounded by `"h"` and `"p"`).

Answer (score 3):

A workaround for the given example could be using lookarounds:

```
import re
REGEX = re.compile(r'(?<=h)[0-9]{3}(?=p)')
test = "hello h889p something"
match = REGEX.search(test)
print(match)
```

Output

```
<re.Match object; span=(7, 10), match='889'>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use string indexing and the `index()` method:

```py
>>> import re
>>> REGEX = re.compile(r'h(?P<num>[0-9]{3})p')
>>> test = "hello h889p something"
>>> match = REGEX.search(test)
>>> test.index(match.group('num')[0])
7
>>> test.index(match.group('num')[-1])
9
```

If you want the results as a tuple:

```py
>>> str_match = match.group("num")
>>> results = (test.index(str_match[0]), test.index(str_match[-1]))
>>> results
(7, 9)
```

Note: As [Tom pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67047356/13746389), you may want to consider using `results = (test.index(str_match), text.index(str_match)+len(str_match))` in order to prevent bugs which may arise from the string having identical characters. For example, if the number were `899`, then `results` would be `(7, 8)`, since the first instance of `9` is at index 8.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `re.Match.span`.

```py
>>> import re
>>> m = re.match("a(?P<num>[0-9]{3})a", "a123a")
>>> m.span("num")
(1, 4)
```